# Find out what percentage of professors has at least one PhD student in SQL

Tags: sql

Let's say in a university, there are Master students, PhD students, and professors. Each student can have only one Professor as his advisor.

How can we find out what percentage of professors has at least one PhD student?

I am thinking of something like:

```
select id as p.profID from professors p 
  where EXISTS (select * from students s 
                where s.advisorID = p.profID and s.enrollmentLevel = "PhD");
```

and using the above query, change it a little to something like:

```
select 100.0 * count(*) from (select id as p.profID from professors p 
  where EXISTS (select * from students s 
                where s.advisorID = p.profID and s.enrollmentLevel = "PhD"))
  / (select count(*) from professors);
```

I don't use SQL every day, so it seems the syntax

```
select count(*) from (select * from students limit 10);
```

is not valid and won't give you back `10`, so the second query above is not valid.  How can it be written?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to address this question.

If some professors have no students, I would go for:

```
select avg( has_student_phd::int ) as phd_ratio
from (select p.*,
             (exists (select 1 from students s where s.advisorId = p.profId and s.enrollmentLevel = 'PhD')
             ) as has_student_phd
      from professors p
     ) p;
```

(This uses Postgres syntax.)

However, if you only cared about professors that have at least one student, then:

```
select ( count(distinct s.advisorId) filter (where s.enrollmentLevel = 'PhD') * 1.0 /
         count(distinct s.advisorId)
       ) 
from students s;
```

Note:  These both use Postgres syntax, but can be easily adapted for MySQL.

Or, the ratio of two subqueries:

```
select (select count(distinct s.advisorId) from students s where s.enrollmentLevel = 'PhD') * 1.0 /
       (select count(*) from professors p)
```

Comment: oh is your solution 2 and 3 `profID` really `advisorID`?

Comment: this is really interesting 3rd solution... it seems if there are N students and M professors, the initial solution I had in the question would take O(N * M) time... but your 3rd solution would take O(N) time. I tried something like `select (select count(distinct advisorID) from students where enrollmentLevel = 'PhD') * 1.0 / (select count(distinct advisorID) from students);` and I can simply use the `students` table, because in my use case I don't even know where to find the professors table yet... maybe it is in an employee table or something like that

Comment: @nonopolarity . . . If performance is an issue, then the first method would would use O(p * log(s)) time, because I would assume appropriate indexes.  The other two methods would be less efficient.

Comment: @nonopolarity . . . As for your first question, I almost always name my foreign keys after the primary key.  I just got confused.  I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the results of `EXISTS` as an integer `1` or `0` for `TRUE` or `FALSE` inside `AVG()`:

```
select 100.0 * avg(
  EXISTS (
    select 1 from students s 
    where s.advisorID = p.profID and s.enrollmentLevel = "PhD"
  )::int
)
from professors p;
```

Remove the explicit cast to int: `::int` for Mysql.